# I gave up with the crossword in the end. It was too difficult

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

I **gave up with** the crossword in the end. It was too difficult.

The reference is from [Phrasal Verb Quiz #10](http://www.ieltsbuddy.com/phrasal-verbs.html) .

> Is "*give up*" a phrasal verb and "*up*" is a preposition?

Or

> Is "*give up with*" a phrasal verb and both "*up*" and "*with*" are prepositions?

My guess is that only the first is correct,

because give up can exist independently in a sentence without "*with*".

Is my understanding correct?

Or both the first and second are correct. Why?

Comment: The phrasal in English is "_give up **on**_ sth."

Comment: I added my reference. Does that mean that Quiz #10 is wrong?

Comment: People often [*give up **chocolate** for Lent*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22give+up+chocolate+for+lent%22), for example, and you wouldn't expect a second preposition there. Nor would I expect one in *give up the **struggle***, say. I think maybe it's illustrative to compare 1) *I gave up the fight* and 2) *I gave up **on** the fight*. To my mind, the first works for a *fighter* conceding defeat, but the second implies a boxing promoter who's decided not to push for some match to take place, or a bored spectator who's decided not to bother watching the rest of the fight.

Comment: @user9418: "wrong" is *way* too strong. It's almost certainly true that *give up **on** sth* is more common (in AmE as well as BrE), but ***with*** is perfectly acceptable in your context.

Comment: Another potentially illustrative example: 1) *I give up **with** you!*, 2) *I give up **on** you!* It's just a nuance that *might* apply, and certainly not something that every native speaker would either use themselves or recognize in another's use, but I'm inclined to see #1 there as more likely to mean *I was trying to persuade you of some specific point, but arguing with you is tedious, so I won't bother any more*. As against #2, which means *I think you're bad and getting worse, and I'm no longer prepared to make any effort to help you*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Following your comment. My further thought is from your saying **with** is perfectly acceptable in the context. Can I say that "I cope with the crossword" has the same meaning of *with* as Quiz #10?

Comment: @user9418: No! To *cope with* something means to deal with it successfully, which doesn't make any sense given the next sentence is *It was too difficult*. But I think your link is to a rubbishy site anyway - as so often happens when pages like that are put together by non-specialists, even though I can make an educated guess as to which *specific* answer they're looking for, not *all* the alternatives are grammatically invalid. I don't know how learners like you could figure out which sites to avoid, but you won't be well served by that one or others like it.

Comment: I agree with @P.E.Dant, if he is referring to modern American English, the structure is *to give up **on** something/someone*, not *give up with*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 for a very important caveat. These sites are ubiquitous. (Not only that, they're everywhere.) This section on phrasals was likely written by a non-native speaker. There are stylometrical clues here and there, e.g. _It is not this straight forward though._

Comment: @Alan Carmack Is it possible that the structure is give up with/on when referring to BRITISH English?

Comment: @P. E. Dant I am glad to read your comment again so that I do not feel like being given up on. And it surprised me that [the site](http://www.ieltsbuddy.com) is not as good as I expected. I think I should read IELTS books published by Cambridge.

Comment: @AlanCarmack The site given by P. E. Dant shows "Ngrams not found: I gave up with the" from the corpus BRITISH English. So I understand clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. "Give up" is a phrasal verb, and "with" is a preposition.

Note: "give up on" is indeed more common than "give up with." But to my ear, both are OK. (According to Google ngrams, "give up on" and "give up with" were almost tied 60 or so years ago, but the "on" version is now by far the dominant one.)

Comment: "Up" is also a preposition!

Comment: The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+gave+up+with+the%2CI+gave+up+on+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20with%20the%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0) for _I gave up on the_ / _I gave up with the_ shows almost zero instances of the "with" usage. Most are Google search errors of the form "I gave up. With the..." The sole modern example is a forum comment by someone who may be a non-native speaker.

Comment: The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+gave+up+with+the%2CI+gave+up+on+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20with%20the%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20gave%20up%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0) is the coolest site on English learning I have ever seen. The site showed "Ngrams not found: I gave up with the" from the corpus BRITISH English. So I know more than before.

Comment: If you just compare "gave up with" and "gave up on" you get much smoother curves, and there are a few other modern examples. But Dant's point is well taken - most of the supposed hits are like Dant describes, or say, "she gave up with a shrug, and...."